# Best way of storing Date & Time in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, datetime, kotlin, jdbc

I'm honestly kinda lost.

I need to store date & time for simple usage, for example storing in the database, sectioned recycler view etc, but there are too many options of how to save data&time, and every article say one is better than the other.

There are `Date`, `Calendar`, `LocalDateTime`, `Instant` etc

My question is what is the current best way of storing date and time?

Comment: In my opinion you should store timestamp as it is standard.
you can convert it back to date time later

Comment: Of course I'm converting this before I insert this into the DB, maybe I wasn't very clear in my question but I meant storing date&time in the model for in app usage @AliAhmed

Comment: As i said, store it as Timestamp in model. and convert it in a format you want to display later

Answer (score 1):

Best way to store date and time in millisecond. Convert your date and time to millisecond and store it.